# Comprehensive HTML page for testing CSS?

Tags: html, css

Looking for example code that uses semantic HTML that I can use to test stylesheets with. The version/doctype is unimportant though HTML5 would be great. When I say "comprehensive" - I am looking for use of definition lists, forms, tables, plus all the usual.
Thanks

Comment: http://www.csszengarden.com/ Enjoy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

[Basic Test Suite for YUI Base](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/base/base-simple.html)

Comment: Yes - good find, unless there something more comprehensive comes through in the next 24 hours, that'll get the big tick, thanks

Comment: In the end, though, it's just a bunch of tags thrown together on a page. You could easily create your own, or change this one to include more HTML5 tags/features. It just depends on what you really want to test.

Comment: Good lord I have been looking *all over* for something like this. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really what you're looking for, but it might come in handy if you find a block of HTML and you need an environment to test it with your CSS... obviously it's not exactly what you are looking for, but it's a pretty cool tool. http://cssdesk.com/

Comment: yeah off topic - but that is very nice